# Path to input files in VS 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio does not seem to be finding input files when I try to compile under "Debug":

```
/* in.dat exists in 

\ProjectName\
\ProjectName\Debug\
\Debug\

*/

string name = "in.dat";
ifstream ifs(name); // nullptr...
```

Are there specific places VS looks for input files? Specifying an absolute pathname did not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, specifying the full pathname will fix the issue. If it didn't, then you specified the path or filename incorrectly.

Comment: By default your data files need to be in the ProjectName folder unless you changed the debugger setting for current working directory that defaults to `$(ProjectDir)`. This is the same behavior for all versions of Visual Studio since at least the late 1990s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Visual Studio Working Directory]

There is a setting in the current project settings for working directory.
When you build a project in visual studio, the executable is run in this directory, regardless of which directory the executable is in.
The working directory is found under Project Settings >> Configuration Properties >> Debugging
More information about properties pages: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019